# foreach a blade view component with dynamic data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i am trying to loop over blade component by passing an array data. it successfully compiled but it is not showing up in the browser and also not giving an error

here is card.blade.php file

```
<div>
    <h1>{{$name}}</h1>
    <h2>{{$age}}</h2>
    <h3>{{$work}}</h3>
</div>
```

here is main file view file

```
    @php
        $arr = [
           
            ['name'=>'1','age'=>'2','work'=>'3'],
            
            ['name'=>'4','age'=>'5','work'=>'6']
        ];
    @endphp

@foreach ($arr as $de)

    <x-card :name={{$de['name']}} :age={{$de['age']}} :work={{$de['work']}}/>
    
@endforeach
```

it also shows attached data when i click view source file

```
    <x-card :name=1 :age=2 :work=3/>
    

    <x-card :name=4 :age=5 :work=6/>
```

but i is not showing up in the browser, browser is blank

Answer (score 1):

You just need to delete `{{}}` syntax from the attributes

```
 <x-card :name="$de['name']" :age="$de['age']" :work="$de['work']"/>
```

for more info check the [`Component-Attributes`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#component-attributes) from the docs

Comment: thank you very much sir, it worked. can we access it like this  
```
 <x-card :name="$de->name" :age="$de->age" :work="$de->work"/>
```

Comment: you need to convert your array to object to achieve that